# How do I move a string from a specific column and row to a different column and row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no idea how to do this, and have not found any documentation on it, but I am 99% sure that it can be done. in other words if I have say a 5 col and 5 row table, and the string is in 1:1 and I want it in 5:5, what would the code look like?(I have done this in excel and access that is why I believe it is possible in sql). Please forgive me if I didn't word this right but I am new to sql and don't know all the lingo just yet. thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better if you make a simple table in your post to illustrate your point including your desired output. It does not have to be complicated nor sophisticated.

Comment: what is the name of the site that allows you to create tables and post a link to that sqlfiddle.com? I think its sqlfiddle.something

Comment: sqlfiddle.com is the name but I could not access for the moment probably later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE TheTable 
   SET column5=(SELECT column1 FROM TheTable WHERE id=1) 
WHERE id=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Database is not Excel, you cannot select value directly based on columnNo, rowNo. What's the use case for it, anyway?

PS. It can be done by some circus tricks and dynamic queries like described in http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,286477,286489#msg-286489, but I don't think it's worth the effort. You should consider redesign of your table structure.

Comment: I think that is what I will do is just redesign the table from scratch, I didn't design the original. but rather than trying to move things around I will just recreate the table and do it the right way. thanks for all the comments everyone

Answer (score 0):

SQL uses the relational model and with that you shouldn't think in terms of row-numbers and column-numbers like you would in Excel.

Instead you have attributes identified by column-names and rows identified by some kind of key that is part of the row:

```
customer-id    firstname    lastname
1853           John         Smith
7751           Nancy        Bush
2222           Any          Name
```

is the same as

```
customer-id    firstname    lastname
7751           Nancy        Bush
2222           Any          Name
1853           John         Smith
```

as far as SQL-databases are concerned.

So rethink your question and eliminate the need for row- and column-numbers.

Comment: so if I think I understand you correctly if I wanted to move the first name john from the firstname col to the lastname col "name" something like, update table set lastname = 'john' were lastname = 'name' and customer-id = '2222', I realize that sql is different, but it was the only way I could convey my point or issue was to put it in terms I was familiar with. but I do thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

You must have an primary key! Then you can modify your table -

```
UPDATE
  table
SET
  column5 = (SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE id = 1)
WHERE
  id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing code to move something, all I had to do was right click and edit table data, guess my instructor didn't want me to know how to do that.